# how to intents (sent to other activity) part of string from textview android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to intents (sent to other activity) part of string from textview? like this image :
[image: intent part of string]

I already settext on textview like this:

```
lbl_checkback_tommorow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_checkback_tommorow);
final String update_profile = "update your profile";
final String hot_news = "Hot news?";
lbl_checkback_tommorow.setText("Check back tommorow,\n and you should be ready to start booking your workout. While you wait, would you want to "+update_profile+", or read some of the interesting posts we have in our "+hot_news);
```

How to make update_profile and hot_news clickable (go to another activity)?

Update: 
Clickable span like this:

```
SpannableString update_profile = new SpannableString("update your profile");
SpannableString hot_news = new SpannableString("Hot news?");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View textView) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
}
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
};
update_profile.setSpan(clickableSpan, 118, 215, 234, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
hot_news.setSpan(clickableSpan, 118, 215, 234, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Check back tommorow,\n and you should be ready to start booking your workout. While you wait, would you want to "+update_profile+", or read some of the interesting posts we have in our "+hot_news);
lbl_checkback_tommorow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_checkback_tommorow);
lbl_checkback_tommorow.setText(builder);
```

Comment: Make multiple textviews and append it later

Comment: yeah, it is easier make multiple textview and just intent two textview, but how to do it with only string like my question?

Answer (score 3):

> How to make update_profile and hot_news clickable (go to another
>   activity)?

Using a `SpannableStringBuilder` you can convert your text in a Spannable object and set a [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) on the part of your text you want to make clickable. When the ClickableSpan's onClick is invoked you can start the Activity.

EDIT

this will do it

```
final String part1 = "Check back tommorow, and you should be ready to start booking your workout. While you wait, would you want to ";
final String part2 = " , or read some of the interesting posts we have in our ";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(part1);
SpannableString update_profile = new SpannableString("update your profile");
SpannableString hot_news = new SpannableString("Hot news?");
update_profile.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
 }, 0, update_profile.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(update_profile);
builder.append(part2);
hot_news.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}, 0, hot_news.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(hot_news);
lbl_checkback_tommorow.setText(builder);
lbl_checkback_tommorow.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: more or less. You need to instantiate a `SpannableStringBuilder` providing the text (SpannableStringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Check back tommorow,\n and you should be..");`, then you will have to look the start index and end index of update_profile and hot_news, and call setSpan on the builder object with those index. After that you will have to set the builder as text for your textView

Comment: what is setspan, is it for coloring the string? just like span in html. I update the code with SpannableStringBuilder and settext as builder. is that right?

Comment: `setSpan` applies the Spannable object to the builder. You can't use `+` to concatenate the strings in this case. Try with `builder.append(hot_news)`